# Ruby Batch Processing an Array for Intercom

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, intercom

I have an array of objects which need processing. I need to send them to a 3rd party system via their API, which only allows me to submit 100 objects at a time.

So let's say I have an array of objects like this

```
myUserArray = [{first_name: 'Jon', last_name: 'Snow'}, {first_name: 'Sansa', last_name: 'Stark'}...]
```

I end up sending this to their API like this

```
intercom.users.submit_bulk_job(create_items: myUserArray)
```

This works fine when the number of objects less than 100 but throws an error when greater than 100 due to their rate limiting, which is fair enough. I have 5000 objects to process, so I need a way of batching the myUserArray into chunks of 100 until they are all done. Would appreciate any advice !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`Enumerable#each_slice`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_slice) comes to the rescue:

```
myUserArray.each_slice(100) do |slice|
  intercom.users.submit_bulk_job(create_items: slice)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If an array of objects is generated continuously on the fly, consider [msg-batcher](https://github.com/ertygiq/msg-batcher) gem.

Here is the code which will call `intercom.users.submit_bulk_job` with up to 100 user objects.

```
require 'msg-batcher'

batcher = MsgBatcher.new 100, 1000 do |batch|
  intercom.users.submit_bulk_job(create_items: batch)
end

myUserArray.each do |user|
  batcher.push user
end
```